# Find largest value in a String of numbers without Math.max()

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

What's wrong in this function, I cannot figure it out:

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
   var arr = numbers.split(" ");
   var largest = arr[0];
   for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i] > largest) {
         largest = arr[i];
      }
   }

   return largest;
 }
```

This:

```
highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6");
```

Returns 6 and it should return 542. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to convert the strings to numbers so they won’t be compared in alphabetical* order. `"20" < "3"` because 2 comes before 3, but `20 > 3`.

Comment: But that's why I split the string into an array.

Comment: you also need to alter the if statement to ```if(+arr[i] > largest)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain `.map(Number)` to `.split()` call to convert string characters to numbers for proper comparison to occur within `for` loop.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var arr = numbers.split(" ").map(Number);
  var largest = arr[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > largest) {
      largest = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return largest;
}

console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for the least code option which is less performant you could use map and sort.

```
return numbers.split(" ")
              .map(Number)
              .sort(function(a, b){return a-b})
              .pop();
```

The map will change all the strings to a number: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

The array function sort will sort ascending: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example

then the pop will take the first value from the array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop?v=example

Answer (score 0):

You `parseInt` while comparing values.

**Code**

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
   var arr = numbers.split(" ");
   var largest = arr[0];
   for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
      if(parseInt(arr[i]) > parseInt(largest)) {
         largest = arr[i];
      }
   }

   return largest;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change this:

```
largest = arr[i];
```

to this:

```
largest = +arr[i];
```

```js
  function highAndLow(numbers){
       var arr = numbers.split(" ");
       var largest = arr[0];
       for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if(arr[i] > largest) {
             largest = +arr[i];
          }
       }

       return largest;
     }
     console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```